# Filling TextBox with data from Database using Combobox c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm currently developing an **enrollment system**, the function I want is when I select a student number from `ComboBox` it will display information like name, year level, age etc. on `TextBox/es`.

This is the code I have now:

```
class MySQL
{
    internal static string host = "localhost";
    internal MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=" + host + ";user=root;database=dbenrollmentsystem");
    internal MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    internal MySqlDataReader dr;
    internal MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();


    public void Connect()
    {
        Disconnect();
        con.Open();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this:

```
   r.Connect();
   r.da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblgeneral WHERE LRN LIKE @search OR LRN LIKE @search", r.con);
   r.cmd = r.da.SelectCommand;
   r.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("search", "%" + cbItems.Text + "%");'
   txtFirstName.Text ="" + r.dr.GetString("FirstName"); 
   r.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   r.Disconnect();
```

But this throws an exception:

> "No current query in data reader"

Can you point whats wrong in my code?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to be more specific. You will be more likely to get a good answer this way.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: also know that you can [edit] your question.

Comment: If you need help with formatting see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting